# Linear Algebra proof, show if a matrix is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing

Let $n$ be a natural number $\geq 2$ and $A$ a matrix $\epsilon M_{n}(K)$. We suppose the matrices $A$ and $I_{n}+A$ are invertible.

Show that $I_{n}+A^{-1}$ is invertible and also $A(I_{n}+A)^{-1}$

Matrix $I_{n}$ is an identity matrix (right?), but what is let's say $I_{3}$?

My effort so far:

So I have this: 
$I_{n}+A^{-1}=AA^{-1}+A^{-1}= ... =A(I_{n}+A^{-1})^{-1}$

Is that correct and if so how do i fill the blank to get to my final answer?

Thank you.

Comment: $I_3=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \cr 0 & 1 & 0 \cr 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 1):

The inverse of $A(I_n+A)^{-1}$ is $(I_n+A)A^{-1}$, because $(CB)^{-1}=B^{-1}C^{-1}$ in general for invertible matrices $C,B$. Hence $A(I_n+A)^{-1}$ is invertible. Furthermore we have  $(I_n+A^{-1})A=A+I_n$. Hence
$I_n+A^{-1}=(A+I_n)A^{-1}$ is invertible.

Answer (score 1):

$$(I+A^{-1})^{-1}=((I+A)A^{-1})^{-1}=A(I+A)^{-1}$$

Comment: So i have this: $A(I_{n}+A)^{-1}=AI_{n}^{-1}+AA^{-1}=AI_{n}+AA^{-1}=A^{-1}+I_{n}$
and 
$I_{n}+A^{-1}=A^{-1}+I_{n}$

correct?

Comment: what?!! your answer is that, and you can't expand it like this (it is so wrong).

Answer (score 0):

There is a hint in the phrasing of the question.

What do you get when you multiply $I_n + A^{-1}$ by $A(I_n + A)^{-1}$?